# Deleting a certain line from a canvas without affecting arc 

Tags: javascript

I want to clear the canvas with condition on each iteration, may be performance. And, the condition is to only want to clear the `line` and not the `arc`.

I already tried `chatGPT`, `save` and `restore` method in JS for save the previous canvas, but it didn't work for me.

This line of code uses the `clearRect` method of the 2D rendering context to clear the canvas by specifying the `x`, `y`, width, and height. But, its clear the whole canvas which I don't want as I mention earlier.

For the better context of my question, you can see this image.

[image]

```
Any answer will be appreciated.
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('cvs')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const CH = (canvas.height = 400)
const CW = (canvas.width = 400)
canvas.style.background = 'black'

const vs = () => {

    let radius = 50;
    let i = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
        let x = Math.cos(i) * radius + CH / 2;
        let y = Math.sin(i) * radius + CW / 2;

        if(i>2*Math.PI)return clearInterval();
        
        /* if I add `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CW, CH);` it's clear the whole canvas, I don't want that type of behavior */
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,1,0,2*Math.PI)
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.stroke();
  
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.stroke();
        
        i += 0.01;
    }, 10)
}

vs();
```

```css
body{
display:grid;
place-items:center;
min-height:100vh;
background:gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already tried `chatGPT`, `save` and `restore` method in JS for save the previous canvas, but it didn't work for me.

Those store-restore the context state, color in use and the like. If you look into the box in the top-right, coincidentally you will see a link "Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned" - that has a reason.

What you need is storing-restoring the bitmap data, `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` are the methods for that. If you're concerned about performance (though it feels a bit early), the `arc()` call can be skipped too, as with this step-size you won't end up with a dotted circle (of course the `strokeRect()` I'm using instead could be then replaced with direct pixel manipulation, but a cool thing is that it provides anti-aliasing):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('cvs')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const CH = (canvas.height = 400)
const CW = (canvas.width = 400)
canvas.style.background = 'black'

const vs = () => {

  let radius = 50;
  let i = 0;

  let backup = false;

  setInterval(() => {
    let x = Math.cos(i) * radius + CH / 2;
    let y = Math.sin(i) * radius + CW / 2;

    if (backup) ctx.putImageData(backup, 0, 0);

    if (i > 2 * Math.PI) return clearInterval();

    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(x, y, 2, 2);
    /*      ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,1,0,2*Math.PI)
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
            ctx.stroke();*/

    backup = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, x + 2, y + 2); // 0 or 1 will have some red pixels

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();

    i += 0.01;
  }, 10)
}

vs();
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

Comment: Storing and retrieving bitmap data by using the functions `getImageData()` and `putImageData().` I looked into it a bit. These techniques operate by transferring the pixel information from a canvas rectangle to a new `ImageData` object. Most image processing or alteration techniques require this. Excluding the path's sketching. You choose to manipulate pixels. It performed as expected. If you were to think about adding additional information or, if you don't mind, would like to add more depth to your response, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Right now I can't think of anything else to add, with this approach you can incrementally "laser-etch" other graphical elements too, without worrying about the existing content, if that's the goal.